# Android : Gridview images shuffled/mixed up

Tags: android, image, gridview, height

I want to do the look of the screenshot below using gridview. I tried setting the layout_height to wrap_content, apparently, upon scrolling, the items are scrambled. Can anyone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: The images are shuffled/mixed-up. Upon initial view, the item 1 is A, item 2 is B and item 3 is C. Then after scrolling, item 1 is B, item 2 is C and item 3 is A.

Comment: No since it is a known android issue. What I did is same height for all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one fixed height for all the images.

Comment: Thanks. I already did that implementation and that's working but I need to do the look of the image above.